# Importing portion of a text file into SAS

Tags: sas

I have a text file that is a publication with tables that I need but also a bunch of other stuff I don't need including paragraphs of text. How would I be able to pull out just the tables I need into a sas dataset?

Comment: I don't know SAS, but updating your question to include how the file is delimited and what identifies the "good" portions of the text file will help people answer. R has a general function named `scan` which I'd usually use for general hacking like this: http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/base/html/scan.html. Maybe you can read up on what `scan` does, and then search for the equivalent functionality in SAS...

Comment: Sometimes just copy & pasting the content into a good text editor (for example Notepad++ on Windows, TextMate on Mac) is the most practical way to proceed. With a series of search&replace operations, make the file into a tab-separated file which you can then paste into Excel or save as is and import in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You could input each line from the text file as one very large character var.  Using PRXMATCH, you can test this line using a Regular Expression.  Depending on the makeup of the text file you can then conditionally control the creation of the dataset based on the Regex matches.